# Using range variable in a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a COUNTIF formula by using a range variable, but there's an extra '' symbol around my variable value.

```
    Dim refRange As Range
    Set refRange = Range(Range("F2"), Range("F2").End(xlDown))

    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(" & refRange.Address(False, False) & ",""PP"")"
```

The output prompts me a NAME error and when i check the value of cell G2, i get this `=COUNTIF('F2':'F23',"PP")`, i wanted to get rid of the '' around the value.

Comment: You're using FormulaR1C1 but passing in an A1 notation address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ActiveCell.Formula instead of ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1:

```
Dim refRange As Range
Set refRange = Range(Range("F2"), Range("F2").End(xlDown))

Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & refRange.Address(False, False) & ",""PP"")"
```